# How can I use generate a tree with multiple data store?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have several Models:

```
ModelA:
fields: [id, name],
hasMany: ModelB

ModelB:
fields: [id, name, attr],
hasMany: ModelC

ModelC:
fields: [id, name, attr]
```

I use a data store to store these nested data from a rest proxy:

```
ModelAStore:
model: 'ModelA'
proxy:{}
```

Now I want them in a tree panel:

The structure will be like:

```
ModelA
|-ModelBInstance
  |-ModelCInstance
  |-ModelCInstance
|-ModelBInstance
|-ModelBInstance
```

When I click on ModelBInstance, the data grid on the otherside will change.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you either

- configure your proxy reader with `typeProperty: 'mtype'` and get your rest API to put `'A'`, `'B'` or `'C'` in that field;

OR

- define your models with property `childType` property: `A` (the store model) will have `childType: 'B'`, `B` will have `childType: 'C'`

It's all in the latest [Tree Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel) manual — scroll to "Heterogeneous node types".

Comment: The model `typeProperty` property needs a defined namespace [Sencha forum post](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?291166-Ext.data.TreeStore-typeProperty-has-no-effect-heterogeneous-node-types-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using 3 diffrent models ? A better solution to me would be to use only one model, and maybe one extra field to save the type of your content :

```
Model:
fields: [id, name, attr, type]
```

According to the doc http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel, the store you use must implement one root field ('children', 'data', ...) that will indicates that the current node got children nodes.
So your model would look like this :

```
Model:
fields: [id, name, attr, type, children]
```

Now if you decide to use this solution you will probably have to refactor the way you generate your data ...

Comment: I tried this method, but it seems in my data base, A, B, C are different classes, so they might have the same id. In this case, the display of the tree seems to have problem.

Comment: I had to deal with the same kinf of problem :) My solution has been to create one single temporary object to return to the tree, adding an extra mark-up to the id. Example : [{id:'A-12', text:'foo'},{id:'B-12', text:'foo'}]. Ext-JS doesn't care if 'id' is an Int value or not